# In Spark, what is left in the memory after a Job is done?

Tags: memory, apache-spark, rdd

I used ./bin/spark-shell to run some experiments and find out the following facts. When running jobs (transformation + action), I notice the memory usage in the *top*. For example, for 5G text file, I did a simple filter() and count(). After the job is done, there are 7g marked as res in the *top* window. I have 100g memory and set the executor memory to be 50g.

Is there anyone know what that 7g is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Spark runs on the JVM, just because Spark may no longer have any references to some memory doesn't mean that that memory will be freed. Even if a garbage collection has been triggered, the JVM may not release the memory back to the OS (this is controlled by `-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio` among other things).